# Creating a random turtle within a shapefile polygon

Tags: netlogo

I am starting with NetLogo and I would like to ask you for some suggestions about the best way to create a random turtle within the boundaries of a shapefile. Does please anybody have any initial direction? I am trying with set x random-pxcor and set y random-pycor but I cannot limit coordinates strictly within the shapefile.

Thank you a lot